# jQuery | Target grandparent siblings

Tags: jquery, html, parent, siblings

On change or on load, whenever a user selects a grid option, I am trying to add the class to pull-left or pull-right to the divs (`block_left`, `media_right`) that are sibling to the selector grandparent `grid`. However I am not able to select the siblings.

Here is the HTML

```
<div data-name="grid">
    <div class="label">
        <label>Grid</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <select>
            <option value="left_right">Left / Right</option>
            <option value="left_media">Content / Media</option>
            <option value="media_right" selected="selected">Media / Content</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-name=“block_left”></div>

<div data-name=“media”></div>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
function blockGrid() {
    var gridSelect = $('[data-name=”grid”] select');

    $(gridSelect).each(function( index ) {
        console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).val() );

        // On Load
        if($(this).val() == “media_right” ) {
            $(this).closest('[data-name="grid"]').find('[data-name="media"]').addClass('pull-xs-left');
            $(this).closest('[data-name="grid"]').find('[data-name="block_left"]').addClass('pull-xs-right');
        };


        // On Change
        $(this).change(function() {
            console.log('Grid changed to ' + $(this).val());

            if($(this).val() == “media_right” ) {
                $(this).closest('[data-name="grid"]').find('[data-name="media"]').addClass('pull-xs-left');
                $(this).closest('[data-name="grid"]').find('[data-name="block_left"]').addClass('pull-xs-right');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('[data-name="grid"]').find('[data-name="media"]').removeClass('pull-xs-left');
                $(this).closest('[data-name="grid"]').find('[data-name="block_left"]').removeClass('pull-xs-right');
            };
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) doesn't look for siblings, it looks for descendants. [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) looks for siblings.

So

```
$(this).closest('[data-name="grid"]').siblings('[data-name="media"]').addClass('pull-xs-left');
// -----------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

...and so on.

Alternately, wrap the entire structure in a common container, use `closest` to go up to that container (e.g., one level above `data-name="grid"`), and *then* use `find`.

---

Side note: I suspect it's just an issue you introduced when asking the question, but the quotes on the siblings are wrong:

```
<div data-name=“block_left”></div>

<div data-name=“media”></div>
```

Those `“` characters should be `"` (or `'`, or no quotes at all, since your values happen fit the requirements for not needing quotes at all).

Comment: Yes it worked! The wrong quotes were added via copy and paste.

Just a follow up, I have the `blockGird` function inside of `$(function(){fiftyBlockGrid();});`

Should this not work when new `<div data-name="grid"></div>` are loaded via ajax?